# excel fast access to a two dimensional array avoiding loop?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, loops

I have many sheets in my workbook that I have to access hundresds of times. Therefore I convert them into array and I work with the array data; much faster.

Asuming an array

```
dim myArray(1 to 1000, 1 to 2)
```

if I look for a value in column 2 according to column 1 the straight fordward way is using a loop

```
for i=1 to 1000
if myArray(i,1)="XXX" then 
myValue=myArray(i,2)
next i
```

since I do taht hundreds of times I wonder if there is something like lookup function for a two dimensional array or something like this:

```
myvalue=function(myarray(1)="XXX",myarray(2))
```

thanks

jose

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to sort the data in the array using QuickSort and use a Binary Search lookup algorithm. Depending on the size of your arrays and the number of times you want to do lookups on the arrays this could be faster. Or you could try using a Dictionary or Collection.

See my blog posts for examples and comparisons of these methods.
 
 https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/developing-faster-lookups-part-3-a-binary-search-udf/  
 https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/ 
 
 https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/comparing-two-lists-vba-udf-shootout-between-linear-search-binary-search-collection-and-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

your code need "**exit for"**

```
For i = 1 To 1000
    If myArray(i, 1) = "XXX" Then
        myValue = myArray(i, 2)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```